# Moderncv \cventry Vertical and Horizontal Alignments

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to insert an image below the year in the first argument of the `\cventry` macro and automatically align that image both vertically and horizontally according to the space taken by the remainder of the entry. I managed to get it horizontally aligned, but not vertically, as shown below. I have tried several options with `\vspace*{\fill}` and other boxes, but none seem to work.

Any clues on how to achieve both vertical and horizontal alignments?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\begin{document}

\cventry{1970\\
\makebox[\hintscolumnwidth]{%
\includegraphics[height=35pt]{misc/stackexchange-black}%
}%
}
{Title}{subtitle}{}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}

\end{document}
```

[image: Horizontal alignment.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED to auto-center *vertically* the image, using `\Xcventry` with an extra argument in which the underset material is provided as argument `#1`.  I use the `\stackunder` macro to achieve it.  It also can take an optional argument which will denote the gap between year and image.

In the MWE below, for the 1st entry, I use `\cventry` and manually center using the optional argument of `\stackunder`.  For the 2nd-4th cases, I auto-center using `\Xcventry`.  The last case is a vanilla `\cventry` with no underset.

EDITED to work with smaller images and multi-line titles and subtitles.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\firstname{Andrew}
\familyname{\newline Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\newcommand\Xcventry[8]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\addstackgap[.5\baselineskip]{\parbox[b]{\hintscolumnwidth}{#1}}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth}{%
    \textbf{#3}, \textit{#4}.\par#7}}%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \edef\stackshift{\the\dimexpr.5\dimexpr\ht2+\ht0-\baselineskip}%
  \cventry{\stackunder[\stackshift]{#2}{%
    \makebox[\hintscolumnwidth]{#1}}}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}%
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% MANUALLY
\cventry{\stackunder[8pt]{1970}{\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{example-image}}
}
{Title}{subtitle}{}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}
% \Xcventry
\Xcventry{\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{example-image}}{1970}
{Title Title Title Title Title Title }{subtitle subtitle subtitle subtitle }
  {}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}
% \Xcventry
\Xcventry{\includegraphics[width=.5\hintscolumnwidth]{example-image}}{1970}
{Title}{subtitle}{}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.
                      \\more text\\text\\text.}{}
% \Xcventry
\Xcventry{\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{example-image}}{1970}
{Title Title Title Title Title Title }{subtitle subtitle subtitle subtitle }
  {}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.
                      text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}
% \cventry with no figure
\cventry{1970}
{Title}{subtitle}{}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a good one, but the image is not vertically centered as the text in the right hand-side grows. Is that achievable using `\usepackage{stackengine}`?

Comment: @dfernan So, just that I understand, you would like to *automatically* adjust the vertical location of the image to be centered to the text on the right?  If manual adjustment is acceptable, the optional argument of the `\stackunder` provides that capability.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry if I did not make that clear in my initial post. Anyway, if automatically centering the image is not easily done, then I guess that the manual offset would do.

Comment: @dfernan Please see revision.

Comment: Your revised answer works, but the image is not properly centered when the title or the subtitle make up more than one line. The horizontal centering is also lost (for smaller images rather than `width=\hintscolumnwidth`). You think that this can be easily fixed?

Comment: @dfernan Fixed both issues.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Steven, how can this be adjusted to horizontally center the year and add a second line of text (also horizontally centered) right below that?

Comment: @dfernan I can't think of an easy way... I am not even sure I fully understand the request.  In the above code, `\Xcventry` sometimes has a year, sometimes an image, as the first argument.  Because it appears on the same line as the **Title**, it is not currently set up to place them on separate lines... I will think some more on it.

Comment: Without adding any new macros, try `\noindent\hspace{\hintscolumnwidth}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax]
  {\def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder{1970}{Here is more text}}
\cventry{}
{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title }
{subtitle}{}{}{text\\text\\more text\\text\\text.}{}`

Comment: I mean to add additional text beneath the year while keeping the logo as it is with the `\Xcventry` macro. In essence, I would like to have the second argument of `\Xcventry` accept newlines as such `\Xcventry{logo}{1970\\additional information}{}...`. Anyway, simply providing `\def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder{1970}{more information}` solves it!

Comment: @dfernan That is easy.  In place of `1970`, place `\stackunder{1970}{text}`.  The default is center alignment, but it can be changed.  If the undertext shouldn't affect the placement of the year, then this would work `1970\bllap{long text}`.  See `stackengine` package documentation for details and options.

Comment: Well, in this case, the year should be aligned with the complementary information underneath to make it look nice. Thanks!